# Can I play sound of several videos being displayed at the same time with one button?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, autoplay, mute

The sound is muted so videos autoplay when page loads and I want one button to disable the mute of all the videos.

I have tried with TagName and Class instead but couldn't manage to make it work.

```js
function toggleMute() {

var video=document.getElementById("dude")

if(video.muted){
 video.muted = false;
} else {
 video.muted = true;
}

}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMute();">
sound on
</button>
<a href=""><video id="baby" poster="" autoplay muted loop>
   <source src="baby.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></a>
<a href=""><video id="joel" poster="" autoplay loop  muted>
    <source src="joel.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></a>
<a href="inside/index.html"> <video id="dude" poster="" autoplay loop  muted><source src="dude.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></a>
```

I expect all videos that are autoplaying to play sound at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, just add all the video element's IDs to the `videos` array!

```js
var videos = ['1', '2']; // Place your video ID's in this array!
function toggleMute() {
  videos.forEach(function(element) { // For each ID in the array, unmute/mute the ID
    if(document.getElementById(element).muted){
      document.getElementById(element).muted = false; //
     } else {
      document.getElementById(element).muted = true;
     };
  });
 };
```

```html
<video id="1" src="https://ia803005.us.archive.org/17/items/big_buck_bunny_201906/big_buck_bunny.mp4" autoplay muted>Your browser doesn't support videos!</video>
<video id="2" src="https://ia803009.us.archive.org/22/items/big-buck-bunny/big-buck-bunny.mp4" autoplay muted>Your browser doesn't support videos!</video>
<button onclick="toggleMute()">Mute/Unmute</button> <!-- When this button is clicked, run the toggleMute() function -->
```

[More about `.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: No problem @CamilaMalenchini but if this answer suits you make sure to accept it!